# How do you refresh a JWT Token when the user authenticated with Cognito Hosted UI in AWS?

Tags: amazon-cognito, serverless, aws-serverless, jwt

Details first:

- Environment = Cognito Hosted UI
- Situation = User signs in using it
- Result = He's successfully authenticated and is redirected to whatever URL to which AWS adds the parameter "id_token=" with whatever value

Sample whatever value after decrypting that token with jwt.io  =

```
{
"at_hash": "some_value_here",
"sub": "the_sub_id_in_cognito",
"aud": "the_client_id_of_the_cognito_app",
"email_verified": true,
"token_use": "id",
"auth_time": 1573661803,
"iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/AWSRegion_CognitoPoolName",
"name": "FirstName LastName",
"cognito:username": "the_username_in_cognito",
"exp": 1573665403,
"iat": 1573661803,
"email": "the_email_in_cognito"
}
```

My question = This token expires within one hour (you can't change this). And in order to keep the user authenticated for more than one hour, you'd have to submit a refresh token using the Cognito InitiateAuth API.

All fine and dandy, except I don't see any refresh token in that JSON :|

Where do I get that refresh token value ? Is it something that gets generated once (and once only) at initial user registration and I should store it in some database ?

Or is that token NOT generated by Cognito Hosted UI because it's not supported and I should stop using it altogether ?

PS: On a different note -> Is Cognito Hosted UI any good or is it bull-crap and I should stop looking into it altogether ?

Thanks and hope you can help me on this ...

Marius

Answer (score 1):

Update.

I've changed my logic to continue to use Cognito Hosted UI and "generate" the HTML pages from Lambda.

I've used the logic from here -> https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/717 to fetch the authentication code and store them as JWT tokens in cookies using Lambda.

I've also had to modify the `App Client Settings` in Cognito as following:

- Allowed OAuth Flows = Just `Authorization code grant`

Basically the logic of using JWT tokens now is being generated "manually" at the Lambda layer.

Hope this helps someone out there...